Flutter is not opening on debug mode
when I run flutter project with out debug mode it fine and opening but when I try to start it on debug mode it is stucking and not opening on virtual device. İt is wierd logs is below:
Connecting to VM Service at ws://127.0.0.1:54937/_bRt9qNAo2E=/wsConnected to the VM Service.D/ProfileInstaller( 3872): Installing profile for com.example.lotus_pilatesE/flutter ( 3872): [ERROR:flutter/runtime/dart_vm_initializer.cc(40)] Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(invalid_icon, The resource app_icon could not be found. Please make sure it has been added as a drawable resource to your Android head project., null, null)E/flutter ( 3872): #0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:646:7)E/flutter ( 3872): #1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:334:18)E/flutter ( 3872): <asynchronous suspension>E/flutter ( 3872): #2      AndroidFlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize (package:flutter_local_notifications/src/platform_flutter_local_notifications.dart:143:12)E/flutter ( 3872): <asynchronous suspension>E/flutter ( 3872):W/FlutterJNI( 3872): FlutterJNI.loadLibrary called more than onceI/ResourceExtractor( 3872): Found extracted resources res_timestamp-1-1728163301184W/FlutterJNI( 3872): FlutterJNI.prefetchDefaultFontManager called more than onceW/FlutterJNI( 3872): FlutterJNI.init called more than onceI/FLTFireBGExecutor( 3872): Creating background FlutterEngine instance, with args: [--start-paused, --enable-dart-profiling]I/FLTFireMsgService( 3872): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!

can anyone help me for resolve this issue

If u just started, try "flutter create . "
